# Adding label in ui-component form

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, ui-form

In **UI component form**, input fields(text and text area) are working allright. But when i try to replace it with a label it gives an error.

**Code:**

```
<field name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">label</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
</field>
```

**Error:**

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The requested component ("label") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

I have researched a lot and couldn't find any worth mentioning solution.

Comment: You want to show some message on backend right?

Comment: @RonakChauhan infact i want to display some dynamic value as label inside form.

Comment: Currently works fine with input field but i have to replace it with label.

Comment: Hi @WasimBajwa, Did you find the solution

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 has it's own Ui module which contains all Form elements including Checkbox, CheckboxSet, Hidden, Input, MultiSelect, Radio, Select, Textarea, Wysiwyg. but It has not a Label element.

So If you want to add a field which contains dynamic text just for visible purpose then you can use container.

uiComponent form:

```
<container name="note_container">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
       </item>
   </argument>
   <htmlContent name="html_content">
       <argument name="block" xsi:type="object"><VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Block\Adminhtml\<CustomClass></argument>
        </htmlContent>
 </container>
```

Custom Class can contains your dynamic value in html or can call custom template file:

```
<?php

namespace <VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Block\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class CustomClass extends Template
{
    protected $_template = 'custom.phtml';
}
```

`custom.phtml` can contains your visible data on form.

Comment: Looking at this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2335247d4ae2dc1e0728ee73022b0a244ccd7f4c/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Form/Element/Factory.php#L26-L55) it seems to me that form element **label** exists.

Comment: Its Form elements which magento 2 supports not UiComponent  of Magnto Supports

Comment: You can find the list of elements in UiComponent Module : `Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element`